# How best to convert CakePHP date picker form data to a PHP DateTime object?

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, forms

I'm doing this in `app/views/mymodel/add.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $form->input('Mymodel.mydatefield'); ?>
```

And then, in `app/controllers/mymodel_controller.php`:

```
function add() {
    # ... (if we have some submitted data)
    $datestring = $this->data['Mymodel']['mydatefield']['year'] . '-' .
                  $this->data['Mymodel']['mydatefield']['month'] . '-' .
                  $this->data['Mymodel']['mydatefield']['day'];
    $mydatefield = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $datestring);
}
```

There absolutly *has* to be a better way to do this - I just haven't found the CakePHP way yet...

What I would like to do is:

```
function add() {
    # ... (if we have some submitted data)       
    $mydatefield = $this->data['Mymodel']['mydatefiled']; # obviously doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you converting this to a PHP DateTime object?  If you're just saving to the db, Cake will perform this transformation for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else comes looking for an answer: CakePHP's generic `Model` class has a method, `::deconstruct()`, that is used to handle this necessary logic internally. You can use it like this:

```
$stringDate = $this->MyModel->deconstruct('fieldname', $arrayDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a Helper that takes in `$this->data['Mymodel']['mydatefiled']` as a parameter, assumes that year/month/day are in the array, and parse accordingly:

```
<?php
/* /app/views/helpers/date.php */
class DateHelper extends AppHelper {
    function ParseDateTime($dateField) {
         $datestring = $dateField['year'] . '-' .$dateField['month'] . '-' . $dateField['day'];
         return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $datestring);
    }
}
?>
```

Or something like that.  I think the DateTime object was added in...PHP 5.2?  CakePHP 1.x is targeted at PHP 4 compatibility, so I don't think there's any "CakePHP way" to do it, at least not for 1.x.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I came to a similar solution myself, by adding it as a method to `AppController`, but the helper is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: heh, well I'm glad that worked, I didn't actually try the code before I posted :)

Comment: I've added a component and a helper for parsing the date time array returned by the datetime fields by cake.  I'm running into an issue parsing for valid times right now.