# filter dates. Cakephp is returning an array instead of a date, is that normal?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, date, filter

I'm building a filter for some paginated lists, and i want to be able to show the elements created between two dates. But I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

**The view:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Logs');?>
<fieldset>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('start',array('type'=>'date'));
    echo $this->Form->input('end',array('type'=>'date'));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Filter');?>
```

**The controller:**

```
...
$conditions['Logs.created BETWEEN ? AND ?'] = array( $this->data['Logs']['start'],$this->data['Logs']['end']);
...
```

the problem is that `$this->data['Logs']['start']` and `$this->data['Logs']['end']` are arrays and i need strings:

```
[Logs] => Array
(
    [start] => Array
        (
            [month] => 04
            [day] => 19
            [year] => 2011
        )

    [end] => Array
        (
            [month] => 04
            [day] => 19
            [year] => 2011
        )
)
```

I know that i could use some php functions to transform the array into string, but there must be some function or something in cake. I feel that i'm not constructing the view correctly

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is normal behavior, your view code is correct. Cake knows how to handle the date when saving. Not too sure when you pass it to `find` though. Does it give an error when you do it that way?

Comment: yeap.. it gives me an error saying that it cant convert an array into string.. the problem is that the filters are not part of any model, it's just a date field that i will use to modify the `find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best bet for you would be to write your own helper function and call it in your controller.

This thread talks about how to create your helper : [How best to convert CakePHP date picker form data to a PHP DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764376/)

You can load it into the controller like so

```
App::import('Helper', 'DateHelper');
$dateHelper = new DateHelper();
```

Also, why not just switch to a regular text input and maybe a JS datepicker? This would solve your problems without having to resort to the helper route. You'd lose the dropdown availability though.

Comment: thanks for your help. i think it will add the code in a component to avoid the import. Cake should add a hidden (or something) that indicates that the field should be threated as a date, therefore converted to a proper format when creating the `$this->data`. I'll just add it to my "reasons why should we use a better/real framework" list for my boss =D

Comment: @pleasedontbelong I actually used the import so the helper is not autoloaded with the controller. You'd have to do the same with a component. You could also consider putting this in app_controller. That's a bit ugly but it will work. Also, I love cake and working with it :P

Comment: but if you create a component, you'll just need to add it to the components list in the controller (or in appcontroller) so you could access them directly using `$this->Time->` And i prefer to stick to the original idea that Helpers should be used in views and Components in controllers

Comment: @pleasedontbelong the problem there is that the component will be loaded everytime your controller is loaded. I'm not sure this is lazy loaded, hence the reason to use App::import.

Comment: u_u thanks for the advice, now i have one more element in my list.. you might want to see this link that i found http://bin.cakephp.org/view/947590030

Comment: @pleasedontbelong yup, on the fly loading. Quite useful that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the time helper, and it's daysAsSql function

```
daysAsSql( $begin, $end, $fieldName, $userOffset = NULL )
```

**daysAsSql** returns a string in the format "($field_name >= '2008-01-21 00:00:00') AND ($field_name <= '2008-01-25 23:59:59')". This is handy if you need to search for records between two dates inclusively.

[See Time helper](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1471/Formatting)

Comment: but if it's a helper i cant use it in the controller

Comment: @pleasedontbelong you can. There's nothing stopping you from accessing it like `$this->Time->dayAsSql()` Or you can get at it using `App::import('Helper', 'Time')`. But I don't think this helper will help with an array

Comment: hmmm yesss, but i find hard to believe that i need to import the helper in the controller just to transform the date, shouldn't there be a Time component? why would someone use `daysAsSql()` in the view??? sometimes i get really disappointed with cake