# CakePHP - Error saving date field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have trouble saving my date field into database using CakePHP.

**Table column name**

```
[User].[dob]
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('dob', array('type'=> 'date', 'label' => FALSE, 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 111, 'maxYear' => date('Y'))); ?>
```

I get the following error when I submit the form -

2011-12-29 00:33:57 Debug: Notice (8): Array to string conversion in [C:\xampp\htdocs\dearmemoir\cake\libs\router.php, line 1573]

This field is part of the Auth User Model. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: You're concatenating an Array like it were a string, I think. Try to replace that with `var_dump(...);` to see what you're really returning there.

Comment: Also, `date('Y') - 111` is a string - an int, maybe try `intval(date('Y')) - 111` ? No, my bad, it works!

Comment: Ah, I think what has happened is that an Array has been passed as an argument in your args array, and cake is trying to concatenate it like a string.

Comment: I replaced [date('Y') - 111] with 1900 and still see the same error!

Comment: Yeah, it turns out PHP won't mind there, but I'd try to do: `<?php var_dump( $this->Form->input('dob', array('type'=> 'date', 'label' => FALSE, 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 111, 'maxYear' => date('Y'))) ); ?>`. Is this the method: http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput

Comment: It returned something like - string(5578) "[mm dd yyyy dropdowns]"!

Comment: @Aram - this is commonly used, not sure if CakePHP have something out of box to resolve this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: had the same problem.. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715694/filter-dates-cakephp-is-returning-an-array-instead-of-a-date-is-that-normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code did the magic for me -

```
$this->data['User']['dob'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->data['User']['dob']));
```

I am able to save data now!

Comment: Where did you added this code. I mean which file and where.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking in the wrong place. The error message is coming from the CakePHP routing (router.php) - i.e. possibly the redirect URL that you are using.

The example code you give looks correct, it almost exactly matches an example from the [Cake cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements):

```
echo $this->Form->input('birth_dt', array( 'label' => 'Date of birth', 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 70, 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18 ));
```

You can add in a check for any [validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689232/cakephp-validate-error).