# Create a new date from php array

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to create a date from array. Is there any function that could  accomplish this? What i know is i can access to fields and create date from that.

```
'endDate' => array(
        'month' => '05',
        'day' => '30',
        'year' => '2017',
        'hour' => '10',
        'min' => '48',
        'meridian' => 'pm'
    )
```

Comment: Are you looking something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322777/how-to-convert-a-date-array-that-was-returned-from-date-parse-back-into-a-date-s I think?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Even this might do the trick
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `DateTime::createFromFormat` and `vsprintf` to construct a time string from the array, and came up with this:

```
<?php
$endDate = array(
    'month' => '05',
    'day' => '30',
    'year' => '2017',
    'hour' => '10',
    'min' => '48',
    'meridian' => 'pm'
);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i a', vsprintf('%s/%s/%s %s:%s %s', [
    $endDate['day'],
    $endDate['month'],
    $endDate['year'],
    $endDate['hour'],
    $endDate['min'],
    $endDate['meridian'],
]));

echo $date->format('d/m/Y h:i a');
```

Outputs (and you can tweak the format:

```
30/05/2017 10:48 pm
```

Actually you probably don't even need to use `DateTime` but I would suggest you do as you can then further manipulate it (add time intervals or change the format), you could probably just do:

```
printf('%s/%s/%s %s:%s %s', [
    $endDate['day'],
    $endDate['month'],
    $endDate['year'],
    $endDate['hour'],
    $endDate['min'],
    $endDate['meridian'],
]
```

Demo: https://eval.in/778600

Comment: is there any way to convert the result to miliseconds. result: `'18/04/2017 04:48 pm'`

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble your value into a value date string then create a new instance of `DateTime` of call `strtotime`.

```
$endtime = [
    'month' => '05',
    'day' => '30',
    'year' => '2017',
    'hour' => '10',
    'min' => '48',
    'meridian' => 'pm'
];
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d h:i A", "{$endtime['year']}-{$endtime['month']}-{$endtime['day']} {$endtime['hour']}:{$endtime['min']} {$endtime['meridian']}");
$time = strtotime("{$endtime['year']}-{$endtime['month']}-{$endtime['day']} {$endtime['hour']}:{$endtime['min']} {$endtime['meridian']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no API function, which can accomplish that. You could implement your own method, in which should look like this:

```
/**
 * Convert given array to DateTimeObject
 * @param $dateArr array containing 'day', 'month', 'year', 'hour', 'min', 'meridian'
 * @return DateTime object
 *
 * 'day' and 'month' must always be 2 numbers
 * 'year' must always be 4 numbers
 * 'hour' must always be 2 numbers (01-12)
 * 'min' must always be 2 numbers (00-59)
 * 'meridian' must always be 2 letters ('am' or 'pm')
 */
function createEndDate($dateArr) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYhia',
        $dateArr['day'] . 
        $dateArr['month'] . 
        $dateArr['year'] .
        $dateArr['hour'] .
        $dateArr['min'] .
        strtolower($dateArr['meridian']));
}
```

Code example:

```
$yourArr => array(
    'month' => '05',
    'day' => '30',
    'year' => '2017',
    'hour' => '10',
    'min' => '48',
    'meridian' => 'pm'
)

$endDate = createEndDate($yourArr);
// see http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php for docs
echo $endDate->format('u');
```